# ASP.NET CKFinder Not Found Folder when click button Browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using `Ckeditor` and `Ckfinder` and I grant to user open folder of user. I am using `ckeditor` click image button then find folder and upload file. But I am using `Ckfinder` upload image . I click button Browser then not find folder.

```
function BrowseServer() {

    var finder = new CKFinder();
    finder.selectActionFunction = SetFileField;
    finder.popup();

}
```

file: config.aspx

```
string path = Session["Path"].ToString();

BaseUrl = "~/Folder/" + path + "/" ;
BaseDir = "";
```

Using `ckeditor` and `ckfinder`. When I click image button show ckfinder and find folder:

[image: Image using ckeditor and ckfinder . when click image button show ckfinder and find folder]

Using `Ckfind`, not finding the folder:

[image: image using ckfinder and not found folder]